# Measure Audio Frequency in android w/o mic

Tags: android, audio, frequency

Is there any API (Provided by Android ) to measure the frequency of sound. I searched about this but didn't get any appropriate API to do that. 
  for example: I  saw a Screen Lock in some device which opens whenever user blow a wind in a particular direction,which gives me an idea about this.

Comment: No such API exists as far as I know.

Comment: @BjornRoche- fine but will u explain the working of that screen lock. :(

Comment: That wouldn't work by frequency detection. I'm guessing it looks for clipping.